# Linkedin v2 API: Cannot get actor displayImage in socialActions endpoint with projections

Tags: linkedin-api

When I'm retrieving social actions of a linkedin share using `socialActions` endpoint, I'm using **projection** to get actor info with `displayImage~`. But it throws following error,

> "displayImage!" : {
>     "serviceErrorCode" : 100,
>     "message" : "Not enough permissions to access: GET-playableStreams /assets/C4E03AQH57nd5w5cWUw/mediaArtifactPublicUrls",
>     "status" : 403
>   }

The query used to get social actions is,

```
curl 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/urn:li:share:543222277889832/comments?projection=(elements*(*,actor~(*,id,vanityName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))))&oauth2_access_token=xxx'
```

When I'm getting person details using `person` endpoint, I can get the `displayImage~` response. Please anyone help me resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn updated [the docs' section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin#retrieving-member-profile-picture) regarding fetching of the display image:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))
```

I've tried it out and it works for me now. Note, that I'm passing the access token through the `Authorization` HTTP header:

```
export ACCESS_TOKEN=xxx
curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
  'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,maidenName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))'
```